# Either, Try, and Validation in Scala

Tags: scala, error-handling, monads, scalaz

I am confused with `Either`, `Try`, and `Validation` of `scalaz`. None of them seems to do what I need. What I need is a simple monad `Result[E, R]` where `E` is an error type and `R` is an result type.

- `Either` is not suitable because it is not a monad (but the *projections* are) and *unbiased*.
- `Try` is not suitable since its error type is `Throwable` and it is not *exactly* a monad
- `Validation` is not a monad at all.

What would you suggest ? Should I write this `Result` type by myself ?

Comment: Use Either projections.

Comment: Why are `Try` not monads ? What monad laws does it break ?

Comment: @paradigmatic - `Try` breaks the unit law in favor of safety, only in the case where an exception is thrown.  If you have `f: A => Try[B]`, then `Try(a).flatMap(f)` has identical behavior to `f(a)` according to the unit law.  But if `f(a)` throws an exception, `Try`'s `flatMap` will catch it.  Hence, in case of exception `Try` is non-monadic because monadicity is irreconcilable with safety from exceptions.  Since the _point_ of `Try` is exception-safety, it favors safety.  (If you restrict yourself to inputs that do not throw exceptions, `Try` is a monad.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're willing to use Scalaz (and it sounds like you are), [`\/`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala) (usually pronounced "disjunction") is exactly what you're looking for—a monadic, right-biased version of `Either`.

It also includes lots of other nice stuff you don't get with the right projection of `Either` in the standard library (`1.right` syntax, combinators like `+++`, converters from `Validation`, etc.).

Comment: Yep, although it's now deprecated in favor of the even-more-awkwardly-named `\/.fromTryCatchThrowable`.